# Create Subrows dynamically inside a row in html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Click to view Image of Table for Refference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZtv6.png)

Here I am creating rows dynamically using Javascript. But as per the requirements as shown in the above image (click the above link to view the image), I need to create subrows within a row, along with the row creation. These subrows should appear for each row created dynamically.
I have used JavaScript to create rows dynamically and also I have used rowspan and colspan attributes to generate subrows like "newCell.rowspan" (shown in the below JavaScript code) but its not working. Please guide me where I am going wrong with the code.

I have also provided the image of what the table should look like. Advance Thanks!

```js
function display(){ 
 
 
 var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);  
 
 //    var m = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');

   var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time' name= 'time'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required></td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td ><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt' name= 'oralamt'  required  ></td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td width ='';><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence'  name= 'oralcommence'  required></td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td width ='';><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' ' id = 'amtgiv'  name= 'amtgiv'  required></td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'urine' name= 'urine'  required> </td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm'  id = 'vomitus'  name= 'vomitus' required></td></tr>";
  newCell.rowspan='7';
   
  
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td width ='';><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'remarks' name= 'remarks'  required  ></td></tr>";
   newCell.colspan='14';
   
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td width ='';><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'remarks' name= 'remarks'  required  ></td></tr>";
    newCell.rowspan='7';
   
   
   
   newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
   newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";
   newCell.rowspan='7';

 
}
```

```css
#myTable1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    }
#myTable1 th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: black;
    width : 180px;
}

.table-fixed{
 
}
  #myTable1 .tbody1{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }
 #myTable1 thead,.tbody1{
  
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1000px; " id="myTable1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan = '2' style="width:100px;">Date Comm.</th>
        <th rowspan='2' style="width:100px;">Drug</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' style="width:100px;">Dosage</th>
        <th  rowspan='2'style="width:100px;">Route Of Admin</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' style="width:100px;">Ordered By</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' style="width:100px;">Time</th>
        <th   colspan ='14' style="width:300px;">Dosage Variation</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' style="width:100px;">Remarks</th>
        <th  rowspan='2' style="width:50px;">Delete</th>
        
       
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>12</th>
      <th>13</th>
      <th>14</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody1">

   
    </tbody>
     <tr id="hiderow">
      <td><button onclick="display()" >Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
```

Comment: Why you combine `cell(td)` command with content which contains `row(tr)`?

Comment: The cheap way to do this is to create a new table inside of the row/cell.  I personally don't really like nesting tables but it does solve this issue fairly easily.